# Winforms - AutoComplete TextBox doesn't show results

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to implement search suggestions in WinForm.  I placed a TextBox on the form; set AutoCompleteMode as SuggestAppend; AutoCompleteSource as CustomSource;

I have implemented TextChanged on the textbox to fetch results and add to AutoCompleteCustomeSource property.  If I debug, I could see the results in this property but UI is not showing up any results.  My code is here:

```
private void txtSearchKey_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AutoCompleteStringCollection searchSuggestions = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        // Clear current source without calling Clear()
        for (int i = 0; i < txtSearchKey.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Count; i++)
            txtSearchKey.AutoCompleteCustomSource.RemoveAt(0);

        if (txtSearchKey.Text.Length >= 3)
        {
            var filteredSearchText = String.Join(",", txtSearchKey.Text.Split(' ').Where(x => x.Length > 2));

            //The below method retrieves the DataTable of results
            var searchResults = MyMethodFetchesResults(filteredSearchText);

            if (searchResults.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                searchSuggestions.Add("No result found");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (DataRow searchResult in searchResults.Rows)
                    searchSuggestions.Add(searchResult["Name"].ToString());
            }
        }

        txtSearchKey.AutoCompleteCustomSource = searchSuggestions;
    }
```

Can anyone please throw some light on this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be trying to implement it yourself; the work is done already. Remove this entire handler for `TextChanged` and start fresh; all you need to do is set the `AutoCompleteCustomSource` and it'll take care of the rest.

Change the signature for `MyMethodFetchesResults` to take no parameters, and then call this method from `Load()` or wherever you're initializing your form:

```
private void LoadAutoCompleteList()
        {
            DataTable d = MyMethodFetchesResults();
            AutoCompleteStringCollection s = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

            foreach (DataRow row in d.Rows)
            {
                s.Add(row[1].ToString());
            }

            txtSearchKey.AutoCompleteCustomSource = s;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to call Application.DoEvents after setting the AutoCompleteCustomSource property??
[Use of Application.DoEvents()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents)

Comment: Yes, this results in an error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Comment: I went with a work around.  I implemented a ListBox below my TextBox and handling show/hide of the control along with populating results into the listbox.  I kind of replicated the bahavior with listbox.